# Vue CSS fade in/out transitions on videos

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, animation, css-transitions

In my project, I have 4 sets of videos all rendering in at the same time but only one is displayed at a time. The user is able to transition to next/prev videos by hitting arrow keys. I'm looking to have a fade in/out transitions on these videos for whenever the user hits a key to go to the next/prev video.

I've tried using vue transitions but they not sure how to used them with `v-show` instead of `v-if` and the tricky part is that all videos only render in once and never get removed, they only get hidden instead. Below is my HTML code for these videos.

```
<div class="video-container" v-show="currentVideo === 1">
      <video @ended="countLoop" ref="video1" muted autoplay>
        <source src="../assets/videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-container" v-show="currentVideo === 2">
      <video @ended="countLoop" ref="video2" muted>
        <source src="../assets/videos/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-container" v-show="currentVideo === 3">
      <video @ended="countLoop" ref="video3" muted>
        <source src="../assets/videos/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-container" v-show="currentVideo === 4">
      <video @ended="countLoop" ref="video4" muted>
        <source src="../assets/videos/video4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah, v-show would only affect on css "show" attribute, the component just got hidden and never removed from the dom if the condition is not satisfied. but v-if is defferent since it would remove the component out of the dom tree.

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

> The difference is that an element with v-show will always be rendered and remain in the DOM; v-show only toggles the display CSS property of the element.
>
> v-if is "real" conditional rendering because it ensures that event listeners and child components inside the conditional block are properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.
>
> v-if is also lazy: if the condition is false on initial render, it will not do anything - the conditional block won't be rendered until the condition becomes true for the first time.
>
> In comparison, v-show is much simpler - the element is always rendered regardless of initial condition, with CSS-based toggling.
>
> Generally speaking, v-if has higher toggle costs while v-show has higher initial render costs. So prefer v-show if you need to toggle something very often, and prefer v-if if the condition is unlikely to change at runtime

you can try some vue framework like vuetify if you are new to vue and want to make transitions easier and more natural.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/transitions/